# How do I find the current window offset using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I open a page, the window offset would be 0 but when i scroll through the page, the offset of the window would increase correspondingly? How can I find the window's offset at any particular point of my web page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if I get the question, but for getting scroll offset use:

```
var scrollOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Comment: This is not wholly reliable if you have wrapping elements. It seems like it does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 13):

You can get the scroll offset of the `window` by using `window.scrollX` & `window.scrollY`. See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollY) on scrollY for more information.

`window.scrollY; // the current vertical scroll offset of the window`

Just thought I would provide the non-jQuery version.

Comment: For custom element you can use `scrollTop` property, for example, `myEl.scrollTop` or  `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

Answer (score 1):

The **.offset()** method is undefined for *window object* or *window element* therefore you 
should use the **.scrollTop()** method to solve your issue :)